# How to create authenticate in certain tabs

Tags: ionic-framework, tabs, ionic3

I just created a new ionic project with Starter template tabs, then i want to authenticate only in tab 3, but when I declare `canActivate: [AuthGuardService]` on routes tabs, I can’t access tabs 3 if auth value is false. because other tabs can be accessed without requiring authentication.
this is my code
**tabs-routing.module.ts**

```
AuthGuardService] on routes tabs, I can’t access tabs 3 if auth value is false. because other tabs can be accessed without requiring authentication.
this is my code

tabs-routing.module.ts

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'tab1',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: () =>
              import('../tab1/tab1.module').then(m => m.Tab1PageModule)
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'tab2',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: () =>
              import('../tab2/tab2.module').then(m => m.Tab2PageModule)
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'tab3',
        canActivate: [AuthGuardService],  /* <-- check auth */
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: () =>
              import('../tab3/tab3.module').then(m => m.Tab3PageModule)
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'tab4',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: () =>
              import('../tab4/tab4.module').then(m => m.Tab4PageModule)
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

**auth-guard.service.ts**

```
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate{

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthenticationService,
  ) { }

  canActivate(): boolean{
    return this.authService.isAuthenticated();
  }
}
```

Comment: this is normal behaviour, the auth guard will prevent the tab from opening when not authenticated so you need to authenticate before trying to access this tab

Comment: yes i can do authentication for all tabs, but this time I only want the 3rd tab  requiring authentication, rest is unnecessary